No stopPropagation for Svelte 5?
I have tried searching all of the documentation for something about how to use stopPropagation for 'onclick' in Svelte 5, but can find nothing for it other than the legacy stuff. Is there any way to do this in Svelte 5?
I have tried something like this:
<div onclick|stopPropagation={someFunc}>
    <button onclick={otherFunc}></button>
</div>

But I get this error: "'onclick|stopPropagation' is not a valid attribute name".
How are you supposed to do this in Svelte 5?

Modifiers are not supported for event properties. Either call the respective function in the handler directly, or use a higher order function to wrap the handler.
<script>
  function someFunc(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // [other logic]
  }
</script>

<button onclick={someFunc}>...

<script>
  // extract to a module for reusability
  function stopPropagation(handler) {
    return e => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      handler(e);
    };
  }

  function someFunc() { /* ... */ }
</script>

<button onclick={stopPropagation(someFunc)}>...

(There is more info on this in the migration guide.)

I would solve it like this:
<div onclick={(e) => { e.stopPropagation(); someFunc();}}>
    <button onclick={otherFunc}></button>
</div>


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
